# is HttpApplication.Init () method get fired only once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

Upon startup of my ASP.NET 4.0 application, I increase count of my application variable inside an override of HttpApplication.Init (). When application runs first time the init method will get called and count will be 1. I noticed that when next time application gets called init method will not get executed and count will always be remained 1.

Is this intended behavior or I am doing something wrong, or my understanding on the HttpApplication.init () is wrong.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Pradeep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpApplication` object is used to process a HTTP request. These are similar to connections and are expensive to create, so the worker process will instantiate as many required and create a pool for the same. Now every request is served by the objects in this pool.

Comment: This does not answers my question

Comment: Since they are created and part of the pool and reused you wouldn't see the numbers incremented. i just expanded on the understanding part

Comment: when the next instance will get created

Comment: I believe its tied to the available no of worker threads and when it exceeds only then additional instances are created.

Comment: what is the maximum Limit? and in which scenario i can use HttpApplication.init() method.

Comment: Is there any programmatic way i can exceed the threads limit and see the new instance created

Comment: @V4Vendetta let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1365/discussion-between-pradeep-and-v4vendetta)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this in the intended behavior: the [Init](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.init.aspx) method is designed to only fire once in order to allow you 'to add custom **one-time** initialization code'

Comment: I read this article from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0xez8f2(v=vs.71).aspx which says The Init method is different from the Application_OnStart event, because it is always invoked on all HttpApplication instances within an application. Application_OnStart is raised only once during an application's lifetime, on the first instance of HttpApplication. I am just confused

Comment: at what condition or when application will get initialized next for my case